# How come DataGridTemplateColumn Visibility Hidden doesn't allocate space for the column?

Tags: c#, wpf, visibility, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have the following DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
 <DataGrid.>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="DeleteColumn" Header="" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DeleteColumnHeaderStyle}" 
                                   Width="25" Visibility="Hidden" IsReadOnly="False" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

The problem with this is that it doesn't allocate the "25" space for the width and seems to provide the same behaviour as using Visiblity.Collapsed.

How do I make it so that the space is allocated?

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the fact `DataGridColumns` aren't actually rendered as part of the VisualTree. You may have to create a custom `HeaderTemplate` and `CellTemplate`, and set those to `Visibility="Hidden"`

Comment: @Rachel Its weird that from code-behind I can make the column visible, and Hidden (turns column to Collapsed), but it doesn't seem to like the Hidden state.

Answer (score 0):

It must be something to be with `VisualTree` layout because `DataGridColumns` does not lie in the Visual Tree of the `DataGrid`. I am not sure though but as a workaround you can play with the `CellTemplate` of the column to reserve the space with following XAML -

```
   <DataGrid>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Visibility="Hidden"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: How would I go about, in code-behind, to make every TextBlock visibile/hidden in the DataGridTemplateColumn? Because currently, I can retrieve the DataGridTemplateColumn, but how would I retrieve the TextBlock?